# method optimization - interface_si

Tags: javascript

If I remove the html from the method arugments and put it into variables does this increase the memory overhead for the function as opposed to inserting it inline.  Obviously the readabily is not as good with the html inserted inline.  Which way is better?

Example 1

```
function interface_si()
      {
      var a=document.forms['f0'].elements,b='f0e';
      check_empty(a,b,'Please enter your credentials')&&check_email(a[0],b,'Please contact <a class="d" href="mailto:support@archemarks.com">support</a> to reset your password')&&check_pass(a,b[1],'Please contact <a class="d" href="mailto:support@archemarks.com">support</a> to reset your password')&&s0('pi.php',serialize('f0')+'&a=0',s3,b);
      }
```

Example 2

```
function i0_0()
  {
  var a=document.forms['f0'].elements,b='f0e';
  var c='Please enter your credentials';
  var d='Please contact <a class="d" href="mailto:support@archemarks.com">support</a> to reset your password';
  var e='Please contact <a class="d" href="mailto:support@archemarks.com">support</a> to reset your password'
  check_empty(a,b,c)&&check_email(a[0],b,d)&&check_pass(a,b[1],e)&&s0('pi.php',serialize('f0')+'&a=0',s3,b);
  }
```

Comment: Local variables are super-cheap. Use them in abundance.

Comment: `i0_0` - is that an emoticon? `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going with readablity for now and pulling the arguments out into variables.